# Adding UITextField input to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to add `UITextField` input into an `NSMutableArray` using the following `IBActions`, connected to the 'did end editing' part of the `UITextFields`:

```
- (IBAction) returnKey1
{
    [textInputOne addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [textInputOne resignFirstResponder];
    [players addObject:textInputOne.text];
}

- (IBAction) returnKey2
{
    [textInputTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [textInputTwo resignFirstResponder];
    [players addObject:textInputTwo.text];
NSLog(@"array: %@",players);
}
```

and I've initialized the players array in the `viewDidLoad` section like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

but the array remains 'nil'. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you already initialized players?

Comment: @Ares I believe I have.

Comment: @Josh Caswell I've looked at all of those and none of them solve my problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the things you've tried to solve your problem, then.

Comment: @JoshCaswell surely you can help me out with what's wrong with the above code regardless of what I've tried to get there.

Comment: I already did. There's not enough info in what you've posted to give any other answer.

Comment: I've initialized players in the viewDidLoad section of the ViewController. Is that the correct place to do it?

Comment: Can you check out what `self` is in the three methods?

Comment: not sure what you mean @Chuck, sorry for the noobiness

Comment: OK, so, just like you have that NSLog of the array, in each of these three methods, add this line: `NSLog(@"self is %@ in %s", self, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);`. Then post the log output here. I have a feeling that will tell us what we need to know. (Could be wrong, but it seems somewhat likely.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextField` doesn't send any actions when the user taps Return.  So you won't receive the “did end editing” action when the user taps Return.

`UITextField` sends “did end editing” when it resigns first responder.  You can make it resign first responder when the user taps Return by setting the text field's delegate and implementing `textFieldShouldReturn:`.  Start by finding the class extension at the top of your `ViewController.m`.  Edit it (or add it if it's not there) to declare that the class conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTwo;

@end
```

Next, implement `textFieldShouldReturn:` in the class to make the text field resign first responder:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Finally, in your xib, connect each text field's `delegate` outlet to the view controller (which is normally File's Owner).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, included all those things, still doesn't seem to be functioning correctly though

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have set the delegates to textfield properly. As you have allocated the players array in viewDidLoad try with following code

```
- (IBAction) returnKey1
{
    [players addObject:textInputOne.text];
}

- (IBAction) returnKey2
{
    [players addObject:textInputTwo.text];
}
```

Both returnKey1 & returnKey2 IBActions assigned to textfield did end editing events.
Now to resign the key board

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

I tried the same thing in one sample project it worked well.